# How to substitute a repeating character with the same number of a different character in regex python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Assume there's a string

```
"An example striiiiiing with other words"
```

I need to replace the `'i'`s with `'*'`s like `'str******ng'`. The number of `'*'` must be same as `'i'`. This replacement should happen only if  there are consecutive `'i'` greater than or equal to 3. If the number of `'i'` is less than 3 then there is a different rule for that. I can hard code it:

```
import re
text = "An example striiiiing with other words"
out_put = re.sub(re.compile(r'i{3}', re.I), r'*'*3, text)
print(out_put)

# An example str***iing with other words
```

But number of i could be any number greater than 3. How can we do that using regex?

Comment: Trivially, `re.sub("iiiiii", "******", string)`. Can you explain your question a bit better? Is it only "i"? is it any repeating letters? Any repeated characters? Is it any six characters starting from the fourth one?...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238139/discussion-between-rabindra-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i{3}` pattern only matches `iii` anywhere in the string. You need `i{3,}` to match three or more `i`s. However, to make it all work, you need to pass your match into a callable used as a replacement argument to `re.sub`, where you can get the match text length and multiply correctly.

Also, it is advisable to declare the regex outside of `re.sub`, or just use a string pattern since patterns are cached.

Here is [the code](https://ideone.com/DBx0AF) that fixes the issue:

```py
import re
text = "An example striiiiing with other words"
rx = re.compile(r'i{3,}', re.I)
out_put = rx.sub(lambda x: r'*'*len(x.group()), text)
print(out_put)
# => An example str*****ng with other words
```